# How to avoid callback hell when using mediatorlivedata in viewmodel to sequence events

Tags: android, android-livedata

I am writing an android app using the architecture best practices provided by Google. I have used the activity making a call to viewmodel which internally calls the repository. In one of the business flows, I need to perform a sequence of steps as below:

1) Fetch the data from table1 in SQLite mobile database that returns liveData.

2) Based on the fields present in table1 within the SQLite database, I need to make an API call to the network to fetch some values.

3) Once I get the result from the network I need to update table2 and table3.

Now as I need to sequence the calls, I am making use of MediatorLiveData to add the sources and in the onChange. However, in order to sequence the calls, I need to keep writing code inside the onchanged method which leads to a callback hell issue.

As I am new to Android development, can someone guide me on the right way to solve this call nesting in Android. Do I need to go with RxJava2 for this? As the android architecture guidelines, only tell us about LiveData, was wondering if there is a cleaner approach available using LiveData.

// Fetch data from SQLite

LiveData liveData1 = repository.getTable1Record();

liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData1, new Observer() {

```
  @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable Table1Row row) {
      liveDataMerger.removeSource(liveData1);
      // Fetch data from network
      LiveData liveData2 = repository.getRecordFromServerOverNetwork();
      liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData2, new Observer() {
           @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable Table1Row row) {
               liveDataMerger.removeSource(liveData2);
               // Fetch data from database again from another table
               LiveData liveData3 = repository.getTable2Record();
               liveDataMerger.addSource(liveData3, new Observer() {
                @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable Table2Row row) {
                  liveDataMerger.setValue(row.MyValue);
               }
              }
           }
      }
  }
```

});

Comment: I think `LiveData` isn't suitable for this case because the task is done once per request. What you are trying to do can be achieved more easily without `LiveData`. If you must use `LiveData`, there are some helpful libraries that allows you to use RxJava-like operators, like [this one](https://github.com/adibfara/Lives).

Comment: Thanks Sanlok for the insight. I am using LiveData as the activity that initiates this flow, depends on a response from this flow and updates the UI based on the response. In order to avoid any memory leak on activity being destroyed I was preferring LiveData. 
Regarding the API you have provided, could you provide a sample on how to chain the requests. I found in RxJava we can chain the request using flatMap function, so is there any equivalent here that can help me out. Thanks.